# How to hide titles in the bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

Is there any option where I can choose the name of a bib entry to appear in the bibliography or not?

E.g. I have in mybib.bib

```
 @article{EMS,
    title = "Eat my shorts",
    journal = "Shelbyville Magazine",
    volume = "123",
    pages = "13 - 14",
    year = "2042",
    author = "B.Simpson",
}
```

Then this:

```
\documentclass[preprint,3p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}

\begin{document}

Lalal \cite{EMS} lalal.

\bibliography{MYBIB}{}

\end{document}
```

results in this output:

> Lalal [1] lalal.
>
> [1] B.Simpson. Eat my shorts. Shelbyville Magazine, 123:13 – 14,
>
> 2042.

but I would like to have

> Lalal [1] lalal.
>
> [1] B.Simpson. Shelbyville Magazine, 123:13 – 14, 2042.

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @HenriMenke yes of course. Can you take a look now please?

Comment: This is completely up to the bibtex style, so you will have to find one that can or modify an existing one (under a new name).

Comment: @daleif where can I find one? I was already looking for different styles, but all I found do include the title in the bibliography

Comment: I don't know any, it is not a usual request. BTW: if you are using `elsarticle` to write an article to, say, an Elsevier journal, then use a bibtex style they recommend, you are not the one determining the layout and what should or should not be printed. As a reader, I'd like to know the title of the things that are cited.

Answer (score 2):

Use a suitable bibliography style like `apsrev`; in the example code I use `filecontents*`, but it's just for making the example self-contained. You can see that it is an “unsorted” style.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{EMS,
    title = {Eat my shorts},
    journal = {Shelbyville Magazine},
    volume = {123},
    pages = {13-14},
    year = {2042},
    author = {B. Simpson},
}
@article{ABC,
    title = {Whatever},
    journal = {Journal},
    volume = {123},
    pages = {13-14},
    year = {2042},
    author = {A. Uthor},
}
@article{DEF,
    title = {Whatever},
    journal = {Journal},
    volume = {123},
    pages = {13-14},
    year = {2042},
    author = {W. Riter},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[preprint,3p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
\bibliographystyle{apsrev}

\begin{document}

Lalal \cite{EMS} lalal \cite{ABC} lalal \cite{DEF}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]