# How to hide the titles of the referenced articles when using a .bib file?

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing, citing, bibliographystyle

I'm writing an article that needs to have the titles of the cited articles absent from the reference list.

This is the way in which I would usually print a reference, for example:

> Pedro Domingos. A few useful things to know about machine learning. Communications of the ACM, 55(10):78–87, 2012.

But in the article that I'm writing, the title should not be there. So it should be printed as:

> Pedro Domingos. Communications of the ACM, 55(10):78–87, 2012.

Clear?
So the question now is: how do I obtain that in LaTeX when I use an external .bib file?

My current LaTeX commands are:

> `\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{article}`
>
> ....
>
> `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}`
>
> `\bibliography{bibliography_file.bib}`

I wanted to try the solution [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/138981/how-to-remove-title-entry-in-the-bibliography-contents) suggested in this forum but I cannot find the `plainnt.bst` file they're refering to here on Overleaf.
I tried another solution suggested on this forum ([2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342750/how-to-hide-titles-in-the-bibliography)) but they did not work to me unfortunately.

Does anyone have a suggestion? Thanks

Comment: Out of curiosity, how should the potential readers of the article be able to find the references?

Comment: I was going to answer this but would have given same answer as the first link you gave, in any case the question is an exact duplicate. If you want to ask a new question, then make an example that is using a modified bst edited as shown in your link and say what error you got. If you don't show your code and just say "it didn't work" it's hard to debug, and just repeating the answers given previously doesn't help anyone.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I suppose the readers will find the articles by the author names, article journal,  article issue, volume, and pages. For example by typing "Communications of the ACM, 55(10):78–87, 2012" online.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for your reply. Sorry I made a mistake, I actually was unable to follow the [1] because I'm using Overleaf and I don't see any plainnt.bst file. I'll edit my question.

Comment: you don't want plainnt you want to start from a copy of unsrt.bst if that is what you are using

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle

Comment: Ok, that sounds unnecessarily complicated. But that is out of scope of the Latex-aspect of the question :)